# Firebase has no response regarding volley request

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-volley

I am new to firebase. I tried to store user data in firebase database using volley. However, firebase has no response regarding my volley request and the database still is null. This is the [tutorial](https://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2016/10/android-real-time-chat-application-using-firebase-tutorial.html) I followed.

This is the volley request I used to connect firebase.

```
public void executeFirebase(){
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, FIREBASE_REGISTER_URL, new Response.Listener<String>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            Firebase reference = new Firebase("https://tradeal-930ad.firebaseio.com/users");
            if(s.equals("null")) {
                reference.child(name).child("password").setValue(password);
                Toast.makeText(activity, "registration successful 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);

                    if (!obj.has(name)) {
                        reference.child(name).child("password").setValue(password);
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "registration successful 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MainPageActivity.class);
                        activity.startActivity(intent);
                        activity.finish();
                        loginUserActivity.finish();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "username already exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            loading.dismiss();
        }

    },new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            System.out.println("" + volleyError );
            loading.dismiss();
        }
    });

    RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity);
    rQueue.add(request);
}
```

Comment: what is the rules of your database?

Comment: @Shaifali Rajput ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"

Comment: @Shaifali Rajput I thought I should still get response from volley request even the rule is not correct

Comment: you need to change the rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the rules of your database to public

```
{  
  "rules" :  
           {     
             ".read"  : true,
             ".write" : true  
           }
}
```

otherwise

```
{  
  "error" : "Permission denied"
}
```

this will be your response

to know more about rules you can visit [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/)